# How Do I Get An EditText To Check If It Equals Any Number In A Integer ArrayList?

Tags: java, android

Ok, so I am trying to get an EditText to check if the value in it equals what is in a Integer array list. First, I have my code to retrieve the string in the Edit Text, then I want to see if the value in the Edit Text equals what I have in a numeric array list. Here is what I tried...

```
  int[] numbers = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

  if (myET.getText().toString().equals(Integer.toString(numbers[9]))) {
      myET.setText("0" + (numbers[9]));
   }
```

It works, but only for the last index in the array list. I want the Edit Text to check if it equals 0 or 1  or 2 and so on until 9. If it does then Edit Text will change the value to like what I have above. I really appreciate the help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<=9 ;i++){
 if (myET.getText().toString().equals(Integer.toString(numbers[i]))) {
      myET.setText("0" + (numbers[i]));
   }}
```